# Laravel show Method with two redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I cant seem to figure this out. I looked around here and different laravel forums for a solution, but no luck. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a show method in my controller, if I delete a record and redirect back to show, the record will not be found since it has been deleted. So I want to check if eloquent returns a model instance, if it doesnt and returns a null, I would like to redirect to the index page.

Currently with this code, event if eloquent returns a model, my show page is tripping out and keeps reloading, like an endless loop. However, if I take the redirect from the if statement and put in a dd('if statement working') to see if it fails the if statement, it works find. So the issue is with the redirect statement.

Here is a snipped of my show method:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $vendor = $this->user->vendors()->find($id);

//if there are no results redirect to the index page.
    if(is_null($vendor)) {
        return redirect()->action('VendorsController@index');

    }

    session()->put('vendor_id', $vendor->id);
    return view('vendors.show', compact('vendor'));
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function show($id)
    {
    $vendor = $this->user->vendors()->find($id);

    if($vendor) {
        session()->put('vendor_id', $vendor->id);
        return view('vendors.show', compact('vendor'));
    }else{
     //redirect to index
     return redirect()->action('VendorsController@index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Silvanus, I tried your solution, but now it stops redirecting after a few times and shows the results of the index page results several times just below the show results.......

Comment: It keeps doing the same thing. It doesnt like the redirect for some reason.....I'm out of ideas. Everything works well othwise

Comment: Try return redirect('/vendors');  - Assuming /vendors is your index route. Try redirect without using action() call

Answer (score 0):

> I have a show method in my controller, if I delete a record and redirect back to show

How about you modify your delete/destroy method, then send it directly to your index page after delete.